# How to remove the top bar in jetpack compose preview functions?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In jetpack compose preview functions, there is a default top bar with a text on it, that is annoying because I want to add my top bar but this text is showing instead:

[image]

How to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

Change your app theme to NoActionBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.TestNami" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```